# How to load a local JavaScript file only within certain components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a JavaScript file that I want to include only in one component once mounted. For example, this JavaScript file (called dashboard.js) should only run when the Dashboard.vue component is active and mounted.

I have tried sticking the code in mounted(), but this won't work because the code relies on `this` being the window, not the Vue instance. I have also tried appending the script to the document.head in the mounted function, but this seems like a big hack and I know there has to be a better way to do this.

```
//Dashboard.vue
<template>
<div>
Dashboard content here
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
      //code that relies on this being the window object here (jQuery stuff)
    }
}
</script>


//dashboard.js
$(function() {
  $div = $('div');
  $div.on('click', function() {
    //do stuff
  });
});
```

I would like for this dashboard.js local script to only be loaded and called when my component gets mounted.

Answer (score 0):

you can import that script in the component:

```
// Dashboard.vue
import * as dashboard from "./dashboard";
```

and then import jQuery inside dashboard.js

```
// dashboard.js
import jQuery from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

$(function() {
  var $div = $("div");
  $div.on("click", function() {
    //do stuff
    alert();
  });
});
```

Comment: I agree with you, I just showed the example that is possible. Any dom manipulation outside of vue.js components is not recommended.